# JSON Schema Is Incorrect In ASP.Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

This is C# EF Core related question.

I am creating 2 entities

```
public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LangName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Language Lang { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

DbContent class code

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
}
```

When I performed the dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate command, LangId column is created in the Contents table.

In Web API project, when I look at swagger at Post for json schema, it looks like this which is not what I expected.

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "language": {
    "id": 0,
    "langName": "string"
  },
  "key": "string",
  "text": "string",
}
```

I am expected to be like this

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "LangId": 0,
  "key": "string",
  "text": "string",
}
```

I am not sure where my mistake is.
Anyone please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you expect a `LangId` property in the generated JSON content when you models do not have a `LongId` property? Also, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which shows how the JSON content is generated.

Comment: You need to explicitly add `LangId` as a property to the class. EF will map it correctly automatically. (You might want to make `Lang` virtual). Then put a `[JsonIgnore]` attribute on the `Lang`.